# Match captured regexes

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string which can be another file to include or a file with a parameter such as:

```
#include virtual="myfile.html"
#include virtual="myfile.html?arg=1"
```

The regex should extract both the file and the param, e.g. something like:

```
m = line.match(/#include virtual=\"(?<vfile>\S+)(?<param>\?+\S+)\"/) unless line.empty?
```

Except with that code above, it only works with if there a myfile.html?something=1

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the desired return value(s) for your example.

Comment: Since this seems to be a URL, I'd fetch it as a whole and extract the query string in a second step via `URI('myfile.html?arg=1').query`

Comment: @Stefan Interesting idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your pattern to include lazy searching and optional last capturing group before an end anchor :

```
/#include virtual=\"(?<vfile>\S+?)(?<param>\?+\S+)?\"/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tgokeq/8)

Answer (score 2):

```
def extract(str)
  str[str.index('="')+2..-2].split('?')
end

extract '#include virtual="myfile.html"'       #=> ["myfile.html"]
extract '#include virtual="myfile.html?arg=1"' #=> ["myfile.html", "arg=1"]
```

or, depending on requirements,

```
def extract(str)
  str[str.index('="')+2..-2].split('?arg=')
end

extract '#include virtual="myfile.html"'       #=> ["myfile.html"]
extract '#include virtual="myfile.html?arg=1"' #=> ["myfile.html", "1"]
```